# setting default form mail in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build a contact form in Rails 5, where the form takes a name, email, and body it to my gmail. Upon clicking "Submit", this form send to my gmail but in my gmail messages from mygmail to mygmail.

routes.rb

```
match '/contact', to: 'me#contact_website', via: 'post'
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "me", action: "contact_website"}, method: "post" , class: "form-group") do %>

<%= text_field_tag(:nama, "", placeholder:"Your Name", required: true) %>
<%= email_field_tag(:email, "", placeholder:"Your Email", required: true) %>
<%= text_area_tag(:pesan, "", placeholder:"Your Massage", required: true) %>
<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

me_controller.rb

```
def contact_website ()
@nama = params[:nama] 
@email = params[:email]
@pesan = params[:pesan]
f @nama.blank? or @email.blank? or @pesan.blank?
 @message = "An error occurred while delivering this message."
render action:"index"
else
    UserMailMailer.new_message(@nama,@email,@pesan).deliver

  @message = "Your messages has been sent."
render action:"index"
#redirect_to root_path, notice: @message
end
```

user_mail_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailMailer < ApplicationMailer
default to: 'nugroho.adty@gmail.com'
#layout "new_message"

  def new_message (nama,emailnya,pesan)

@nama = nama
@emailnya = emailnya
@pesan = pesan


mail(from: emailnya, subject: 'Contact Request From Website')

#render "new_message"
  end

end
```

new_message.html.erb

```
<p>Message from  <strong><%= @nama %> </strong></p>

<p><%= @pesan %></p>
```

in new_message.html.erb email from form can show but in user_mail_mailer.rb mail mail(from: emailnya) not showing email from contact